# Validating Login Fields

Tags: vb.net

Good-day SO,

Thanks to all your help, my VB.net skills are improving.  I have another small request - need help with some code that I'm having trouble with during debugging.

My intent is to have the code - on a button.click event - check the Username and Password fields and return an error depending on which is wrong.  Or if both are wrong, return a different error message.  I've set the username as parts and the password as parts (still learning how to use external authentication).

So, here's the code - how can I make this work?

```
If Not TextBoxUsername.Text = "parts" Then
        Label3.ForeColor = Color.Red
        Label3.Text = "Invalid Username..."
        TextBoxUsername.SelectAll()
        TextBoxUsername.Focus()
    Else
        If Not TextBoxPassword.Text = "parts" Then
            Label3.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Label3.Text = "Invalid Password..."
            TextBoxPassword.SelectAll()
            TextBoxPassword.Focus()

            'NOTES:
            'This section of the code is being skipped, and I can't figure out why.  
        ElseIf TextBoxUsername.Text <= "parts" And TextBoxPassword.Text <= "parts" Then
            Label3.ForeColor = Color.Red
            Label3.Text = "Invalid USERNAME and PASSWORD..."
            TextBoxUsername.SelectAll()
            TextBoxUsername.Focus()
        Else
            Label3.ForeColor = Color.Green
            Label3.Text = "Login successful..."
            FormMain.Show()
            Me.Close()
        End If

    End If
```

I am reading up on using the SELECT CASE statement to see if I can use that instead - but haven't figured out how to make that work yet.  Thanks.

//Kismet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I absolutely agree with Brian here :)

However one small point. Never let the user know whether the username was incorrect or the password was incorrect from "Security" perspective.

Here is what I propose

```
If TextBoxUsername.Text <> "parts" or TextBoxPassword.Text <> "parts" Then
    Label3.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Label3.Text = "Invalid USERNAME OR Invalid PASSWORD. Please Try Again"
Else
    Label3.ForeColor = Color.Green
    Label3.Text = "Login successful..."
    FormMain.Show()
    Me.Close()
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well.  I tested it and it worked fine.  I understand where you're coming from concerning Security, however, due to my user's "dumb" approach to anything computer I decided to "dummy-proof" the application as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT CASE` isn't really the appropriate solution here. Try this:

```
If TextBoxUsername.Text <> "parts" And TextBoxPassword.Text <> "parts" Then
    Label3.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Label3.Text = "Invalid USERNAME and PASSWORD..."
    TextBoxUsername.SelectAll()
    TextBoxUsername.Focus()
Else If TextBoxUsername.Text <> "parts" Then
    Label3.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Label3.Text = "Invalid Username..."
    TextBoxUsername.SelectAll()
    TextBoxUsername.Focus()
Else If TextBoxPassword.Text <> "parts" Then
    Label3.ForeColor = Color.Red
    Label3.Text = "Invalid Password..."
    TextBoxPassword.SelectAll()
    TextBoxPassword.Focus()
Else
    Label3.ForeColor = Color.Green
    Label3.Text = "Login successful..."
    FormMain.Show()
    Me.Close()
End If
```

A few stylistic notes:

1. Label3 needs a proper name. Don't use the default if you're going to refer to it in code. It's fine now, but when your forms get more complex you'll struggle to remember the difference between label1, label6, and label23. Don't try and keep that all in your head. Instead, use descriptive names for controls.
2. Note the use of `<>` which means "does not equal". This sometimes reads a little better than the `Not` operator because you can read left-to-right without having to double back and remember that the clause has a `Not` before it. This is really a matter of personal preference than technical correctness though.

Comment: @Brian Willis -  Thanks for that answer and the stylistic suggestions, I have taken them into advisement and revised my code accordingly.  I did test your suggestion out and it worked perfectly.